# How to add and remove single propertys to ngStyle?

Tags: angular

How can I add properties to an existing **ngStyle**-Attribute without setting it completely new?

For now I found a workaround by setting [`style.float`] but in future I want to do something like my posted code.

I tried it with:

```
obj.style = obj.style + { float: 'right' }
```

I searched with multiple Search Phrases. More and more I assume its not possible.

```js
obj.style: { color: 'red' }

< .... [ngStyle]="obj.style"...>


public ButtonClickAddFloating(obj) {

// Target: obj.style: { color: 'red', float: 'right' }

}


public ButtonClickRemoveFloating(obj) {

// Target: obj.style: { color: 'red' }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helpfuel answers. I decided to use the following solution:  
setFocusDurchTastatur(sektion) {
    sektion.style =  { ...sektion.style, border : '3px solid #eb780a'};
    sektion.tastaturFocus = true;
  }

  disableFocusDurchTastatur(sektion) {
    delete sektion.style.border;
    sektion.tastaturFocus = false;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
this.ngStyle = { ...this.ngStyle, fontFamily: 'Roboto' };
```

Be aware that this syntax **DOES NOT** remove the previous styles from the objet. If you want to remove it, then either re-assign it, or set the value to undefined.

You can also destructure your object to remove properties :

```
{ fontFamily, ...rest } = this.ngStyle;
this.ngStyle = rest;
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this in addition to delete-method. See my comment under my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) or [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const obj = {style: {color: 'red'}}
obj.style = {...obj.style, float: 'right' }
obj.style = Object.assign({}, obj.style, {color: 'blue'})
console.log(obj)
```

Anyway this probably wont carry on the styles added outside the scope of ngStyle AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

```
public objStyle: any = {'background-color': 'red'};

public addFloat(): void {
  this.objStyle = Object.assign({ 'float': 'right' }, this.objStyle);
}

public removeFloat(): void {
  delete this.objStyle['float'];
}
```

And html:

```html
<p [ngStyle]="objStyle">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<button (click)="addFloat()">Add float</button>
<button (click)="removeFloat()">Remove float</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `delete` to remove property from you object example

```js
 var obj={style:{color:'red', float: 'right'}}

console.log('Before delete',obj)

delete obj.style.float   //remove peroperty here

console.log('after delete',obj)

obj.style['float']='left';  //set float property again here

console.log('Added float property again',obj)
```

Comment: The question was about adding a style without having to write all the previous styles again. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Maryannah delete will not rewrite whole object it will remove only one property

Comment: "The question was about **adding a style without having to write all the previous styles again**".

Comment: I don't know why you are stuck to this heading only OP wants two methods one to add float property other to remove float property any way you may be right thanks for your opinion

Comment: Regarding deleting it was an usefuel answer for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Maryannah check out OP comment